# Files not appearing immediately on remote system after SFTP put command

Tags: centos, nfs, sftp

I'm encountering a bizarre issue. I'm sending files to a remote machine using SFTP's `put` command. However, even though my machine says the transfer is finished, the files don't appear immediately in the remote machine's file system. Instead, they all suddenly come in at once, with timestamps to match (within a few seconds of each other even though there was actually about a five minute gap between each transfer). What could cause this? Is it possible that SFTP is caching the files somewhere on the remote machine?

Further details: both machines are running flavors of Centos 6. There's no antivirus installed. It's a direct `put` to the directory where the files should be appearing: there's no watcher program moving files around or anything like that. There *is*, however, a watcher program copying files *out* of that directory as they appear.

Comment: What filesystem? Does it occur if you use `-f` flag to `put` command?

Comment: crazy idea - is some antivirus program temporarily quarantining them? less-crazy idea - a file-watcher program that's watching for incoming sftp files to process?

Comment: Updated with more information. @Jakuje: haven't tried -f, but if that's even a thing doesn't it mean the file is getting cached somewhere in the interim? The SFTP man page says "when uploading files, this feature is only enabled if the server implements the 'fsync@openssh.com' extension." How would I check for that?

Comment: If you type the sftp `ls` command after transfer, are the new files listed?

Comment: Is the destination filesystem a network-mounted filesystem, _e.g._ NFS or s3fs, where the directory information might be being cached, thus resulting in sometimes stale directory listings for clients?

Comment: Sorry if I respond slowly, the local machine is an embedded system that I can't open a terminal in. I'm trying to get some tests set up in my environment.

Comment: @Castaglia The destination folder for these files is an NFS folder. It gets mounted on a third machine. I'm looking at the directory on the machine with the folder however, not the third machine.

Comment: Sounds like an NFS cache.  So the timeline is: upload file, file doesn't appear in directory listing of server, upload another file a few minutes later, neither file shows, then suddenly both files appear with timestamps within a few seconds of each other?  Are they closer to the second upload?  When do they show up from the third system?  And what's the NFS server you're using?

Comment: @mkomarinski The timestamps are after the last upload. The case I'm looking at has ~10 files that were uploaded minutes apart. The NFS server is bundled with CentOS, I think it's just nfs-utils or something like that.

Comment: @mkomarinski Would the NFS cache actually prevent me from seeing files on the _server_? That sounds very strange. Wouldn't that mean NFS is caching the files before they're even written to disk?

Comment: @txteclipse Yes, it's strange, which is why you're not getting many good answers.  NFS v2 didn't acknowledge writes until it was written to disk, so no write cache.  You can [read](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/#section_a) up a bit more on how NFSv2 and v3 operate.  If the files are small enough, you might be running into 'safe asynchronous writes' but I don't think that would take minutes to flush.